# My Android cocos2d-x game crash on some samsung phone, but the logcat not show where it crash

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash, cocos2d-x, crash-dumps

cocos2d-x use android-ndk, I use cocos2d-x 2.1.4 edition,

I use lua as game script, my game will crash in some cheaper mobile phone, like samsung s7562c, e120l. game will crash in different place. the logcat seems like below:

```
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106): backtrace:
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106):     #00  pc 00041020  /dev/ashmem/decode_fd (deleted)
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106):     #01  pc 00007878  <unknown>


03-26 10:58:18.135: I/DEBUG(11409): backtrace:
03-26 10:58:18.135: I/DEBUG(11409):     #00  pc 00077018  /dev/ump
03-26 10:58:18.135: I/DEBUG(11409):     #01  pc 00006108  <unknown>
03-26 10:58:18.135: I/DEBUG(11409): stack:
```

My problem is why the backtrace has so little meaningful information?

Are there some method I can get more information from ndk crash ?

It seems that crash happens in the memory related driver, so I have to reduce the memory usage in the game? Are there any good methods to location such memory problem?
thanks

This is one full dump file:

```
03-26 13:01:17.773: I/DEBUG(106): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-26 13:01:17.773: I/DEBUG(106): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/cs023gzc/cs023g:4.2.2/JDQ39/G3502UZCUAMK1:user/release-keys'
03-26 13:01:17.773: I/DEBUG(106): Revision: '7'
03-26 13:01:17.773: I/DEBUG(106): pid: 17997, tid: 18116, name: Thread-14144  >>> com.caesars.cnnozomi <<<
03-26 13:01:17.773: I/DEBUG(106): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 5a3ac020
03-26 13:01:18.195: I/DEBUG(106):     r0 55b830a8  r1 55a8ce00  r2 55ab8328  r3 ffffffff
03-26 13:01:18.195: I/DEBUG(106):     r4 00000003  r5 00002710  r6 57f50c5c  r7 55a8bd00
03-26 13:01:18.195: I/DEBUG(106):     r8 55b830a8  r9 569f4e58  sl 588aa834  fp fffffff2
03-26 13:01:18.195: I/DEBUG(106):     ip 55b73670  sp 5674eba8  lr 588aa87c  pc 5a3ac020  cpsr 28000010
03-26 13:01:18.195: I/DEBUG(106):     d0  19a7448034753ef3  d1  414fffff3e91e9ee
03-26 13:01:18.195: I/DEBUG(106):     d2  412bcccd413f0000  d3  bd1b0e004442d4dc
03-26 13:01:18.195: I/DEBUG(106):     d4  3e789e26404068a4  d5  3f2aaaba41000000
03-26 13:01:18.195: I/DEBUG(106):     d6  40b432e33db5794b  d7  19b4b26300000103
03-26 13:01:18.195: I/DEBUG(106):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
03-26 13:01:18.195: I/DEBUG(106):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
03-26 13:01:18.195: I/DEBUG(106):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
03-26 13:01:18.195: I/DEBUG(106):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
03-26 13:01:18.195: I/DEBUG(106):     d16 41b9b4b2630f1aa0  d17 3f50624dd2f1a9fc
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106):     d18 41ca3a9f79800000  d19 0000000000000000
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 3ff0000000000000
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106):     d22 8000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 8000000000000000
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106):     d26 3ff0000000000000  d27 4bb44bb44bb44bb4
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106):     d28 00ff00ff8c73837c  d29 57a8ac5300ff00ff
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106):     d30 0100010001000100  d31 0100010001000100
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106):     scr 60000012
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106): backtrace:
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106):     #00  pc 00041020  /dev/ashmem/decode_fd (deleted)
03-26 13:01:18.203: I/DEBUG(106):     #01  pc 00007878  <unknown>
03-26 13:01:18.210: I/DEBUG(106): stack:
03-26 13:01:18.210: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb68  5674eba8  [stack:18116]
03-26 13:01:18.210: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb6c  56d51810  
03-26 13:01:18.210: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb70  00000063  
03-26 13:01:18.210: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb74  563d87c0  
03-26 13:01:18.210: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb78  569f4e18  
03-26 13:01:18.210: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb7c  56f3b1f8  /mnt/asec/com.caesars.cnnozomi-1/lib/libcocos2dlua.so
03-26 13:01:18.210: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb80  5674eb8c  [stack:18116]
03-26 13:01:18.210: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb84  56f41488  /mnt/asec/com.caesars.cnnozomi-1/lib/libcocos2dlua.so (lua_rawget+32)
03-26 13:01:18.210: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb88  fff80000  
03-26 13:01:18.210: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb8c  000007f8  
03-26 13:01:18.210: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb90  57f4fb28  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb94  57f4facc  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb98  55a8bd00  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eb9c  55a8b1c0  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eba0  df0027ad  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674eba4  00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):     #00  5674eba8  57f56330  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          ........  ........
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):     #01  5674eba8  57f56330  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebac  fffffffb  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebb0  57f4facc  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebb4  55a8b1c0  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebb8  00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebbc  00000002  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebc0  00000008  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebc4  55a8b1f0  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebc8  00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebcc  00000001  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebd0  00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebd4  5674ec78  [stack:18116]
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebd8  56451f3c  
03-26 13:01:18.218: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebdc  5643d2a8  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebe0  5674ec8c  [stack:18116]
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):          5674ebe4  56f41d58  /mnt/asec/com.caesars.cnnozomi-1/lib/libcocos2dlua.so (lua_pcall+72)
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106): memory near r0:
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83088 00000000 55000400 2a7d3f80 00000005  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83098 657a6973 00000058 00000020 00000023  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b830a8 00000000 ff000400 10738f5f 0000000a  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b830b8 47746567 4b646972 00007965 0000002b  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b830c8 55b874f8 55000400 456d29b6 00000012  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b830d8 6c697455 6f68522f 7247626d 6c2e6469  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b830e8 00006175 00000023 00000000 55000400  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b830f8 42bdf858 00000009 6d6f6852 69724762  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83108 00000064 00000093 55b832a8 05020704  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83118 00000008 55b5eb30 55b83180 55b83180  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83128 00000003 00000000 00000089 00002000  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83138 55b7e8e0 0000000f 00000003 55b83180  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83148 55b83187 55b83187 00000555 00000310  
03-26 13:01:18.226: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83158 00000237 0202023e 00010334 03020337  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83168 01020420 00020340 00000000 55a90300  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83178 55a8fed0 55a90900 02010101 73020202  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106): memory near r1:
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8cde0 55a8c338 55a8cd18 55a8b2c4 56f2b27d  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8cdf0 00000000 00000000 00000028 00000023  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8ce00 00000000 00000400 c387ca2f 00000007  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8ce10 6e695f5f 00786564 00000000 00000023  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8ce20 00000000 00000400 ff730758 0000000a  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8ce30 656e5f5f 646e6977 00007865 00000023  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8ce40 00000000 00000400 d99ceba0 00000004  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8ce50 63675f5f 00000000 00000000 00000023  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8ce60 00000000 00000400 d507f06e 00000006  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8ce70 6f6d5f5f 00006564 00000000 00000023  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8ce80 00000000 00000400 7b144f9b 00000004  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8ce90 71655f5f 00000000 00000000 00000023  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8cea0 00000000 00000400 078aa1ef 00000005  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8ceb0 656c5f5f 0000006e 00000000 00000023  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8cec0 55a8cf80 00000400 eaa74b47 00000004  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8ced0 746c5f5f 00000000 00000000 00000023  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106): memory near r2:
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab8308 55ab8528 00010804 55a8c338 55ab8698  
03-26 13:01:18.234: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab8318 55a8b2c4 56f2b25d 55ab8340 0000001b  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab8328 55ab8888 00000804 55a8c338 55ab7568  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab8338 57f50c58 00000023 55ab82e0 00010804  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab8348 55a8c338 55ab85b0 55a8b2c4 56f2b581  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab8358 00000020 00000023 55ab8250 00010804  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab8368 55a8c338 55ab81f0 55a8b2c4 56f2b27d  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab8378 00000000 0000018b 55ab8250 fffffff7  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab8388 55a8cee0 fffffffb 55ab8410 55ab8410  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab8398 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab83a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab83b8 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab83c8 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab83d8 00000000 00000000 55b05998 fffffff4  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab83e8 55a8c990 fffffffb 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     55ab83f8 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106): memory near r5:
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     000026f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     00002700 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     00002710 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     00002720 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     00002730 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     00002740 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     00002750 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.242: I/DEBUG(106):     00002760 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     00002770 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     00002780 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     00002790 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     000027a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     000027b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     000027c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     000027d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     000027e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106): memory near r6:
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50c3c 00172000 57f56358 0000001b 00000008  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50c4c 57f50cf8 57f50d17 57f50d17 00170857  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50c5c 00020427 00040301 80090454 00000510  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50c6c 00000437 00010610 00020710 0204043e  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50c7c 04000416 0403041e 00020448 80120454  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50c8c 00010309 80080454 00000510 00000437  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50c9c 01020615 00020710 0204043e 04000416  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50cac 00020448 80080454 00000510 00000437  
03-26 13:01:18.250: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50cbc 00010610 02020715 0204043e 04000416  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50ccc 04020414 00020448 00010047 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50cdc 55b830a8 0000000a fffffff2 00000002  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50cec fffffff2 00000001 fffffff2 02010101  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50cfc 02020202 02020202 04040303 04040404  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50d0c 06060404 06060606 73080606 00666c65  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50d1c 00782000 00792000 64652000 64496567  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     57f50d2c 00200000 00000002 0000002b 57f5b768  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106): memory near r7:
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bce0 0048005d 0070006f 0015002d 006d006f  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bcf0 0067006f 0051006f 002a006f 00220070  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bd00 56f32c80 56f32d18 56f32db0 56f32e48  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bd10 56f32ee0 56f32f70 56f32ffc 56f33048  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bd20 56f33094 56f33118 56f3319c 56f331d8  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bd30 56f33214 56f3324c 56f33284 56f332b8  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bd40 56f332ec 56f33310 56f33344 56f33388  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bd50 56f333cc 56f33424 56f3347c 56f334d8  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bd60 56f33514 56f33570 56f335c8 56f33620  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bd70 56f3367c 56f336b8 56f33714 56f3376c  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bd80 56f337c4 56f33820 56f3385c 56f338b8  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bd90 56f338f4 56f33944 56f3396c 56f33994  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bda0 56f339b8 56f339dc 56f33a00 56f33a3c  
03-26 13:01:18.257: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bdb0 56f33a70 56f33adc 56f33b40 56f33b78  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bdc0 56f33bac 56f33bec 56f33c2c 56f33c94  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55a8bdd0 56f33cec 56f33d00 56f33d14 56f33da0  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106): memory near r8:
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83088 00000000 55000400 2a7d3f80 00000005  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83098 657a6973 00000058 00000020 00000023  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b830a8 00000000 ff000400 10738f5f 0000000a  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b830b8 47746567 4b646972 00007965 0000002b  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b830c8 55b874f8 55000400 456d29b6 00000012  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b830d8 6c697455 6f68522f 7247626d 6c2e6469  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b830e8 00006175 00000023 00000000 55000400  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b830f8 42bdf858 00000009 6d6f6852 69724762  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83108 00000064 00000093 55b832a8 05020704  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83118 00000008 55b5eb30 55b83180 55b83180  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83128 00000003 00000000 00000089 00002000  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83138 55b7e8e0 0000000f 00000003 55b83180  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83148 55b83187 55b83187 00000555 00000310  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83158 00000237 0202023e 00010334 03020337  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83168 01020420 00020340 00000000 55a90300  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     55b83178 55a8fed0 55a90900 02010101 73020202  
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106): memory near r9:
03-26 13:01:18.265: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4e38 00000003 fffffff2 00000001 fffffff2  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4e48 00000003 fffffff2 55ab8328 57f4fadc  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4e58 57f99418 fffffff4 00000017 fffffff2  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4e68 0000001f fffffff2 00000003 fffffff2  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4e78 57fa6280 ffffffff 57f99418 fffffffd  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4e88 55a91e70 fffffff4 55afe3a0 fffffff4  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4e98 55ad1d80 fffffffd 55b244b8 fffffffb  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4ea8 55adc8b0 fffffff4 55b244e8 fffffff7  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4eb8 00000000 ffffffff 55afe068 fffffffb  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4ec8 55afe3a0 fffffff4 56f350e0 57f5beb4  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4ed8 55afe0e8 00000082 569eebd8 fffffff3  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4ee8 55ada350 fffffffb 55afe088 fffffff4  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4ef8 55ab9b88 fffffff7 00000001 ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4f08 55b228e0 55b8a4f8 569eebd8 fffffff3  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4f18 00000000 40a34e00 00000000 40a07b80  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     569f4f28 55a91e70 fffffff4 55afe3a0 fffffff4  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106): memory near sl:
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa814 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.273: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa824 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa834 e303c670 e345c5b7 e3e0b00d e30380a8  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa844 e34585b8 e30b7d00 e34575a8 e3025710  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa854 e2871c11 e1a00008 e599e01c e5994018  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa864 e37e000e 1b6c05ea e3540002 bb6c05e9  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa874 e3540002 1b6c05e8 e599e004 e5996000  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa884 e37e000c 1b6c05e5 e596e01c e5983008  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa894 e596a014 e003200e e0822082 e08aa182  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa8a4 e1ca20d8 e3730005 01520008 0b6c05db  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa8b4 e59aa010 e35a0000 1afffff8 e5966010  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa8c4 e3560000 0b6c05d5 e596a01c e35a0001  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa8d4 1b6c05d2 e5966014 e1c622d0 e3730005  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa8e4 01520001 1b6c05cd e596e01c e596a018  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa8f4 e37e000c 1b6c05c9 e3006cac e34567f5  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa904 e59a801c e358000f 1b6c05c4 e59aa014  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106): memory near ip:
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     55b73650 55b73bb8 00010804 55a8c338 55b6d748  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     55b73660 55a8b2c4 56ebfe21 55b71768 0000001b  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     55b73670 55acfa78 00000804 55a8c338 55ae6350  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     55b73680 55b86038 0000018b 55b18228 fffffffd  
03-26 13:01:18.281: I/DEBUG(106):     55b73690 55a8b260 fffffffb 00000000 55b737c0  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     55b736a0 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     55b736b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     55b736c0 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     55b736d0 55ade768 fffffffd 55ade0d8 fffffffb  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     55b736e0 00000000 00000000 55ad1d80 fffffffd  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     55b736f0 55ab9e38 fffffffb 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     55b73700 55ab93b0 fffffffd 55ab8d20 fffffffb  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     55b73710 00000000 00000000 55ade0d8 fffffffd  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     55b73720 55ab9078 fffffffb 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     55b73730 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 ffffffff  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     55b73740 00000000 00000000 55aba170 fffffffd  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106): memory near sp:
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     5674eb88 fff80000 000007f8 57f4fb28 57f4facc  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     5674eb98 55a8bd00 55a8b1c0 df0027ad 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     5674eba8 57f56330 fffffffb 57f4facc 55a8b1c0  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     5674ebb8 00000000 00000002 00000008 55a8b1f0  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     5674ebc8 00000000 00000001 00000000 5674ec78  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     5674ebd8 56451f3c 5643d2a8 5674ec8c 56f41d58  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     5674ebe8 fffffffd 567deb28 fffffffd 56eca6a1  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     5674ebf8 567deb28 00000001 00000001 56eca629  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     5674ec08 50ada608 0000000c 3f1c8a05 56eca499  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     5674ec18 00000000 56eca47b 56ce0018 56faf6f9  
03-26 13:01:18.289: I/DEBUG(106):     5674ec28 56faf5cd 56438840 00000001 3f1c8a05  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5674ec38 00000000 56fb00cb 56faff95 56437a38  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5674ec48 5643d298 00000000 56451f44 56fc42bd  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5674ec58 56437a38 38e00001 4c452250 56fc43c5  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5674ec68 56fc43a1 56fe32e1 4d7f321a 409682d4  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5674ec78 56451f3c 00000001 420aea70 00000008  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106): code around pc:
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac020 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac030 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac050 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac060 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac070 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac080 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.296: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac090 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac0a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac0b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac0c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac0d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac0e0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106):     5a3ac0f0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106): code around lr:
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa85c e599e01c e5994018 e37e000e 1b6c05ea  
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa86c e3540002 bb6c05e9 e3540002 1b6c05e8  
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa87c e599e004 e5996000 e37e000c 1b6c05e5  
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa88c e596e01c e5983008 e596a014 e003200e  
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa89c e0822082 e08aa182 e1ca20d8 e3730005  
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa8ac 01520008 0b6c05db e59aa010 e35a0000  
03-26 13:01:18.304: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa8bc 1afffff8 e5966010 e3560000 0b6c05d5  
03-26 13:01:18.312: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa8cc e596a01c e35a0001 1b6c05d2 e5966014  
03-26 13:01:18.312: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa8dc e1c622d0 e3730005 01520001 1b6c05cd  
03-26 13:01:18.312: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa8ec e596e01c e596a018 e37e000c 1b6c05c9  
03-26 13:01:18.312: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa8fc e3006cac e34567f5 e59a801c e358000f  
03-26 13:01:18.312: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa90c 1b6c05c4 e59aa014 e1ca2fd8 e3730005  
03-26 13:01:18.312: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa91c 01520000 1b6c05bf e1ca2fd0 e3730009  
03-26 13:01:18.312: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa92c 1b6c05bc e3a0a00a e1c900d8 e371000e  
03-26 13:01:18.312: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa93c 1b6c05b8 e2508001 6b6c05b6 e599e014  
03-26 13:01:18.312: I/DEBUG(106):     588aa94c e5994010 e37e000e 1b6c05b2 e152000c  
03-26 13:01:18.312: I/DEBUG(106): memory map around fault addr 5a3ac020:
03-26 13:01:18.312: I/DEBUG(106):     5a26b000-5a36b000 /dev/ashmem/decode_fd (deleted)
03-26 13:01:18.312: I/DEBUG(106):     5a36b000-5a46b000 /dev/ashmem/decode_fd (deleted)
03-26 13:01:18.312: I/DEBUG(106):     5a46b000-5a56b000 /dev/ashmem/decode_fd (deleted)
03-26 13:01:18.625: I/DEBUG(106): !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 17997
```

after ndk-stack translate

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/cs023gzc/cs023g:4.2.2/JDQ39/G3502UZCUAMK1:user/release-keys'
pid: 17997, tid: 18116, name: Thread-14144  >>> com.caesars.cnnozomi <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 5a3ac020
Stack frame #00  pc 00041020  /dev/ashmem/decode_fd (deleted)
Stack frame #01  pc 00007878  <unknown>: Unable to open symbol file local/armeabi//<unknown>. Error (123): Unknown error
```

Comment: Did you run the project with an attached debugger on the device, or are these reports you've received from users respectively through the store?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D  I run the project with an attached debugger on the device. These are collected from logcat.

Comment: This log won't help anything. You should use logcat along with command `adb logcat | ndk-stack -sym MyGame\proj.android\obj\local\armeabi` with correct path accordingly your project.

Comment: @Cocos2dx ndk-stack  can't translation it into meaningful data,  because the backtrace part only have two lines.

Comment: It throwing `Unable to open symbol file local/armeabi` error. Did you build project in debug mode? I mean did you used `APP_OPTIM:=debug` flag in your `Application.mk` file? Also make sure your symbol path is correct may be your device might have different architecture in case your symbol path might have changed.

Comment: @Cocos2dx yes  because error happens  in /dev/ashmem/decode_fd which is a kernel device driver, ndk-track can't find the symbol file for the device driver, that program is in android source code, not in cocos2dx source code. I test several device, the error all seems to happen in these share memory driver. So I think it just because the GPU　memory is not enough to put my game texture. Now I try to use etc1 format texture in android device, this will reduce much memory.  Perhaps this method will solve my problem, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`Error happens in android device driver. These device is shared memory device which seems to be used for cpu and gpu. According to Android OpenGLES document`
 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#textures

`etc1 format is supported in most android device. So I use this format to compress my game texture. This will save much memory for gpu. I modify cocos2d-x code to make etc1 support alpha channel, according to the below doc.`
http://malideveloper.arm.com/cn/develop-for-mali/sample-code/etcv1-texture-compression-and-alpha-channels/

for more information about etc1 please check wiki
`en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ericsson_Texture_Compression`

I don't have enough reputation so I can't paste more links for my research sorry.